# Bokeh Plots Y-axis auto scale when plotting multiple lines in same figure

Tags: python, bokeh

I am plotting multiple lines in same figure with source being same data frame. This is causing the plot to show by default y-axis max range to 100. To see values which are more than 100 I have to zoom out.

Here is the current graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neCEU.png)

I probably should be using multiline to do what I am doing but currently I have this

```
         datetime_tick_formats = {
            key: ["%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"]
            for key in ("seconds", "minsec", "minutes", "hourmin", "hours", "days")}

    p1 = figure(title="Usage MB",plot_width=1400, plot_height=600,x_axis_type="datetime")
    p1.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
    p1.yaxis.axis_label="Usage(mb)"
    p1.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(**datetime_tick_formats)
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_heap,line_width=2,color="red",legend_label='heap')
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_nonheap,line_width=2,color="green",legend_label='non heap')
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_metaspace,line_width=2,color="blue",legend_label='metaspace')
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_compressed_class_space,line_width=2,color="black",legend_label='class space')
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_g1_oldgen,line_width=2,color="aqua",legend_label='G1 OldGen')
    p1.line(x='log_time',y='usage_mb',source=source_codecache,line_width=2,color="violet",legend_label='codecache')
```

Is there a way to make sure the axis auto scales for multiple line in the plot?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. By default Bokeh auto-ranges over all glyphs, unless you explicitly set the range values manually, in which case it respects what you ask for.  Have you set `y_range` elsehwhere?

Comment: @bigreddot I added the little snippet to my original comment which shows what I am doing before the plot. I do not think i am setting anything explicitly.

Comment: Nothing about that looks out of the ordinary, so the issue must be elsewhere. In order to investigate, a complete [Minimal Reproducing Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is necessary.